# "Beide" and "beiden": when do I add the "n"?

Tags: article

When do you add *n* to *beide*? I had thought you only added an *n* to *beide* when the word was used in the dative case. However, I have discovered sentences where *beide* follows non-dative articles such as *diese* and *die* and yet still ends in *n*. For example:

> Diese beiden Frauen
>   Die beiden Autos

Comment: Please read up about weak inflection (which is what _beide_ after an article or demonstrative pronoun uses) in your grammar of choice.

Comment: One actually needs a whole sentence (or enough information as which is the role of that nouns in the sentence) to be able to deduce the endings: *diesen beiden Frauen schenke ich Blumen* or *diese beiden Frauen kennen mich* oder *wegen dieser beiden Frauen ...* usw.

Answer (score 0):

Die **schönen** Frauen! Die **beiden** Frauen! Die **beiden schönen** Frauen! ;-)

--> use it like an adjective -  (only exists in plural of course...)

**Zwei** schöne Frauen! -> **Number**
**Die** schönen Frauen! -> **Article** as determinator
**Beide** schönen Frauen! -> use it like a **determinator** when there isn't any article

**Zwei** schöne Männer/Frauen/Kinder!
**Die** schönen Männer/Frauen/Kinder!
**Beide** schönen Männer/Frauen/Kinder!